# Similar code in C# for a code in C++

Tags: c#, c++, hex

Somebody could help me with this? I have this C++ code and I need it converted to C#.

```
sprintf(szChkSum,"%03x",nChkSum);
```

The "%03x" is what is troubling me. this makes a 3 digits hexadecimal number, right?
I need to do the same in C#, how I do this?

Sorry about the poor english.

Comment: Three hexadecimal digits with _leading zero_.

Comment: Take a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = nChkSum.ToString("X3");
```

Comment: It works when I run it -- hex digits zero padded to three characters.  What output are you getting?  Can you post more context?

Comment: yes, im sum ASCII values, the result is 83641 , and the answer is 49b ... i have this example with this results in C++ , and I have to make a similar code in C#...

Comment: after the sum, when i get the 83641 value, i have this two lines of code what make the "magic" ... see that helps in something...
}
  
  sprintf(szChkSum,"%03x",nChkSum);
 }
 
 
 return _strdup((char*) szChkSum+strlen(szChkSum)-3);

Comment: looks like your C return value is just grabbing the three least significant hex digits.  In C# you could call s.Substring(s.Length-3) after the hex string conversion that I posted above.

Comment: yes, is something like this, i will try something like this, very very thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) at msdn.

You can find good example here too http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Answer (score 0):

```
szChkSum = string.Format("{0:x3}", nChkSum);
```